# Why does my extern trained model not work on my own computer?

Tags: python, yolo

I have trained my customized yolo model with 1 class and 200 photos on an external computer (loss couldn't get tiny = 5.3577552518885305).
Now I want to use this model on my computer with my webcam but it doesn't detect the objects at all.
Is it not enough to mail the cfg file to my computer put it in my cfg map and then just load it?

```
options = {
        'model': 'D:/darkflow-master/cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg',
        'load': 3300,
        'threshold': 0.1,
        'gpu': 1.0
                }
```

What I also don't understand: in the ckpt folder of the external computer I can see changes following the training but in the cfg folder the date modified of the model (tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg) is still "old" = unchanged.

I can't do the training on my own computer as it is a work-computer and the training took 15 hours...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's your model problem rather than bugs in your predicting program? Besides, how do you save models to your ckpt and cfg folder? Paste your code may help.

Comment: My predicting program is actually a working code from a course. This is how I have trained the model: python ./flow --model ...\cfg\tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load ...\darkflow-master\bin\tiny-yolo.weights --train --annotation ...\Annotation --dataset ...\Train --gpu 0.8 --epoch 300

Comment: Files in `.cfg` seems like just configuration of your models. You should test with model weights in your ckpt folder.